# Half power frequencies is -6dB or -3dB

Tags: matlab, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I have to design a 1024 order band pass filter in matlab. The pass band frequencies are [376 480] and fs=16kHz.It was written in documentation of MATLAB that "the cutoff frequency is the frequency at which the normalized gain of the filter is –6 dB". How can it  be -6dB? It should be -3dB right.

Answer (score 9):

The definition of the cut-off frequency is arbitrary. Different design methods use different definitions. If you define the cut-off at $-6\textrm{ dB}$, it means that the amplitude of a sinusoidal input at the cut-off frequency is halved at the output. Consequently, its power at the output is a quarter of what it was at the input. If you want the power to be halved at the cut-off frequency, you need to define the cut-off as the $-3\textrm{ dB}$ point.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better. On a historical note, in the 1960's and 1970's, arguably the best spectrum analyzers in the world were made by HP and Tektronix.  HP analizers specified filter widths at the 3dB points, Tek specified them at the 6dB points.  Often there were Tek analyzers that were a better buy than the HP ones if you compared apples-to-apples, but the HP ones looked better on paper.  This was an ongoing point of contention between Engineering and Marketing at Tek.

Answer (score 3):

To add detail to Matt’s good answer:

-6dB is preferred in certain filter design approaches. For example when windowing the ideal impulse response for a brick-wall filter, the designated brick-wall transition is frequency will be right at the -6dB point after windowing in time.

One reason -3dB is preferred in most analog filter designs as well as digital IIR filters is the -3dB point is the deviation at the asymptotic slopes in a Bode plot (as is -45 degrees in phase). For example, a simple first order low pass filter with a “pole at 1 KHz” ( which really has a pole in the left half plane on the real axis the same distance away from the origin as $j 2\pi 1000$ but that is an aside), will asymptotically be zero dB from DC to 1 KHz and then go down asymptotically -20 dB/decade starting from 1 KHz and above. The actual magnitude will be -3 dB lower at 1 KHz to these asymptotic lines. Multiple poles at the same location will increase this deviation accordingly but serves to show one example of the convenience of -3dB.

So there are reasons of convenience for each and depends what algorithms and processes we are using.

Answer (score 1):

To address the question in the title, which you do not reiterate in the text: $3\mathrm{dB}$ down is half power, yes.  $6\mathrm{dB}$ down is half *amplitude*.

As already discussed, there are good reasons to use either one in defining a filter's cutoff frequency, which is why both are used, in different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this notation may depend on the topology, too.

For example; let's say that you have a first-order, basic low-pass filter. It is known that at the corner (cut-off) frequency level in the magnitude spectrum of its transfer function, the signal power at its output is half of the input, i.e., the power gain is $-3 dB$.

On the other hand, think about the case in which you add another low-pass filter in series to the older one and assume that they are identical. Now, at the cut-off frequency, the power gain is now $-6 dB$ as the new filter divides the input power (i.e., the output of the first filter) by two.